# Fast Scrolling, the content disappears from the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a webpage with static content, without scrolling effects or javascript events on scrolling. My issue is that if I scroll fast from top page to bottom, the content disappears and appears again after 0.5 seconds, Even divs with colored backgrounds disappear for an instant and that appears again.
Could you please let me know why this is happening? Why my content do not stay visible no matter how fast I scroll the page, I would like a scroll-like on the stack overflow website.

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: If the page is static and server rendered and there are no loading events, your content should stay on the page. Unless your divs hold some really heavy re-painting content that would trigger re-paint? Can you share the link or show a reproducible example of it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not have a link, but it is simple so let me explain. The body is white, and the content is grey "divs" with text and the height of the webpage is 3500 px "different divs". If I'm scrolling from the top to bottom fast, using the scroll bar or the mouse, the divs are cut and only the background is visible.

Comment: I think you will have to create an example which you put into your question and that we can run to see the problem as nothing I've tried so far gives me the symptoms you describe. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how fast scrolling is causing the content to disappear from the viewport.

It could be that your computer is struggling with the rendering if the content of the divs is very heavy.

See example attached, that has no rendering problems.

```js
var colorArray = ['#FF6633', '#FFB399', '#FF33FF', '#FFFF99', '#00B3E6', 
          '#E6B333', '#3366E6', '#999966', '#99FF99', '#B34D4D',
          '#80B300', '#809900', '#E6B3B3', '#6680B3', '#66991A', 
          '#FF99E6', '#CCFF1A', '#FF1A66', '#E6331A', '#33FFCC',
          '#66994D', '#B366CC', '#4D8000', '#B33300', '#CC80CC', 
          '#66664D', '#991AFF', '#E666FF', '#4DB3FF', '#1AB399',
          '#E666B3', '#33991A', '#CC9999', '#B3B31A', '#00E680', 
          '#4D8066', '#809980', '#E6FF80', '#1AFF33', '#999933',
          '#FF3380', '#CCCC00', '#66E64D', '#4D80CC', '#9900B3', 
          '#E64D66', '#4DB380', '#FF4D4D', '#99E6E6', '#6666FF'];

colorArray.forEach(color => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.height = "200px";
    div.style.width = "100%";
    div.style.background = color;
    div.textContent = color;
    app.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
#app {
  min-height: 3500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works well, I have to find the bug that cut the divs during scrolling.